# Where clause by only number-convertable rows

Tags: sql, oracle, casting, numbers

I have a table with 2 columns like this

```
COLNUM | COLSTR
---------------
1      | 001223
2      | 002234
3      | ds2-dd
4      | 003344
```

I would like to make query like this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CAST(COLSTR AS NUMBER) IN (1223,3344)
```

But since 4th row can not cast to number, query fails. I could create a view which would eliminate non-number-transformable rows, but I would like to make this with one query. How do I do it?

Oracle 11g.

Thanks.

Comment: i think it's better not to cast `COLSTR` and to compare with string values like `WHERE ltrim(COLSTR, '0') in ('1223', '3344')`

Comment: `where colstr like '%1223' or colstr like '%3344'`?

Comment: @jarlh  '091223' is like '%1223' and should not be selected

Comment: @FrankOckenfuss, yes, you're right. Never mind, hope OP learns to avoid mixing data types in a column.

Comment: I've found an answer with using something like "COALESCE(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR( COLSTR, '^(-|+)?\d+(\.|,)?(\d+)?$')), NULL)" but the query with where in (123,223) takes a looot of time.

Comment: Do you have an index on `COLSTR`?

Comment: @FrankOckenfuss, dunno actually but I ended up not using LIKE statement whatsoever. Anyway, regex was the best aproach at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use regular expression

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(COLSTR,'^[0-9]$')
```